# LINQ Order by with the list inside list

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have an API LINQ list called `examContents`. Currently, it has been ordered by `SectionId` & `DisplayOrder` (no 1 & 2 as in the below picture). Now I want to add **Tag Tile** also as the third ordering option. Is there a way to do that in C# LINQ?

I tried adding `.ThenBy(x=>x.Tags)` & `.ThenBy(x=>x.Tags.Title)` next to `DisplayOrder` along with `.OrderBy(t=>t.Type).ThenBy(t=>t.Title)` next to **Tags** list. But it does not work. Can someone please help me on this?

[image]

```
var examContents = await this._context.ExamContents
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.IsNewVersion && versionIds.Contains(x.VersionId))
    .Select(x => new ExamContentModel
    {
       Id = x.Id,
       VersionId = x.VersionId,
       LearningOutcomeId = x.LearningOutcomeId,
       SectionId = x.SectionId,
       Title = x.LearningOutcome.Title,
       AssignedQuestionCount = x.AssignedQuestionCount,
       DisplayOrder=x.DisplayOrder,
       IsNewVersion=x.IsNewVersion,
       Questions = x.LearningOutcome.Questions.Where(x => x.Category == QuestionCategory.Certification).Select(y => new Question
       {
           Title = y.Title,
           Category = y.Category,
           Status = y.Status,
           IsDraft = y.IsDraft,
           PublishedQuestionId = y.PublishedQuestionId,
           ExamVersionId = y.ExamVersionId
       }),
       Tags = x.LearningOutcome.LearningOutcomeTags.Select(t => new Tag
       {
           Id = t.TagId,
           Title = t.Tag.Title,
           Type = t.Tag.Type,
           IsRemovedFromLO = t.IsUntaggedFromLO
       })
    })
    .OrderBy(x=>x.SectionId).ThenBy(x=>x.DisplayOrder)
    .ToListAsync();
```

The error I am getting is:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet\r\n    .Where(e => e.IsNewVersion && __versionIds_0\r\n        .Contains(e.VersionId))\r\n    .Join(\r\n        outer: DbSet, \r\n        inner: e => EF.Property<Nullable>(e, "LearningOutcomeId"), \r\n        outerKeySelector: l => EF.Property<Nullable>(l, "Id"), \r\n        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<ExamContent, LearningOutcome>(\r\n            Outer = o, \r\n            Inner = i\r\n        ))\r\n    .OrderBy(e => e.Outer.SectionId)\r\n    .ThenBy(e => e.Outer.DisplayOrder)\r\n    .ThenBy(e => DbSet\r\n        .Where(l0 => EF.Property<Nullable>(e.Inner, "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable>(e.Inner, "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable>(l0, "LearningOutcomeId"))\r\n        .Join(\r\n            outer: DbSet, \r\n            inner: l0 => EF.Property<Nullable>(l0, "TagId"), \r\n            outerKeySelector: t => EF.Property<Nullable>(t, "Id"), \r\n            innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<LearningOutcomeTag, Tag>(\r\n                Outer = o, \r\n                Inner = i\r\n            ))\r\n        .OrderBy(l0 => l0.Inner.Type)\r\n        .ThenBy(l0 => l0.Inner.Title)\r\n        .Select(l0 => new Tag{ \r\n            Id = l0.Outer.TagId, \r\n            Title = l0.Inner.Title, \r\n            Type = l0.Inner.Type, \r\n            IsRemovedFromLO = l0.Outer.IsUntaggedFromLO \r\n        }\r\n        ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

[image]

Comment: could you post your code as text please?

Comment: Please do not share code as picture. Please amend your question. Please also elaborate on: *But it does not work*.

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer code added as a text

Comment: @LahiruSandaruwan Your question and your code does not match. In the code you have `order by sectionId`, in the question you have `order by type`. So, which one is correct?

Comment: @LahiruSandaruwan What version of net core are you using?

Comment: @PeterCsala What do you mean by codes does not match? In the picture and the text I have used '.OrderBy(x=>x.SectionId).ThenBy(x=>x.DisplayOrder)' My question is that I need to order by Tag Tile also along with SectionId & DisplayOrder as the third-order by.

Comment: hi, the Tag is part of a subcollection (cardinality 1:n), you need to order that subcollection to achieve this, or aggregate the resulting collection -> try for instance
`...Tags =<your select>->OrderBy(t=>t.Tag) .... <Your currenctOrderBy>`

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer I did that also. But still gives the same result. Question edited

Comment: in that case, you need to evaluate that on the client side instead, try putting a `ToList` between your where and your select. (see that link in the error message)
that forces the Implementation to deliver the collection to your runtime structures and resolve the linq there, instead of trying to push it down to EF and DB . if that doesnt work, also fetch the questions and the tags to the client side

Comment: How do you plan to order by Tags? Remove `ThenBy(x => x.Tags)`

Comment: Why not first materialize list in memory using tolistasync and then order in memory

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps:

```
var examContents = await this._context.ExamContents
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.IsNewVersion && versionIds.Contains(x.VersionId))
            .SelectMany(examContent => examContent.LearningOutcome.learningoutcometags, 
                (examContent, tag) => new { examContent, tag })
            .Select(examContentAndTag => new ExamContentModel
            {
                Id = examContentAndTag.ExamContent.Id,
                VersionId = examContentAndTag.ExamContent.VersionId,
                LearningOutcomeId = examContentAndTag.ExamContent.LearningOutcomeId,
                SectionId = examContentAndTag.ExamContent.SectionId,
                Title = examContentAndTag.ExamContent.LearningOutcome.Title,
                AssignedQuestionCount = examContentAndTag.ExamContent.AssignedQuestionCount,
                DisplayOrder = examContentAndTag.ExamContent.DisplayOrder,
                IsNewVersion = examContentAndTag.ExamContent.IsNewVersion,
                questions = examContentAndTag.ExamContent.learningoutcome.questions
                     .where(x => x.category == questioncategory.certification)
                     .select(y => new question
                     {
                         title = y.title,
                         category = y.category,
                         status = y.status,
                         isdraft = y.isdraft,
                         publishedquestionid = y.publishedquestionid,
                         examversionid = y.examversionid
                     }),
                tags = examContentAndTag.tag
                    .select(t => new tag
                    {
                        id = t.tagid,
                        title = t.tag.title,
                        type = t.tag.type,
                        isremovedfromlo = t.isuntaggedfromlo
                    })
            })
            .OrderBy(examContentAndTag => examContentAndTag.ExamContent.SectionId)
            .ThenBy(examContentAndTag => examContentAndTag.ExamContent.DisplayOrder)
            .ThenBy(examContentAndTag => examContentAndTag.tag.type)
            .ThenBy(examContentAndTag => examContentAndTag.tag.title)
            .ToListAsync();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0